# Изменить кодировку извлекаемых файлов с использовании DotNetZip

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

```
var ExistingZipFile = ZipPath;
string TargetDirectory = ExtractPath;

using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
{
    foreach (ZipEntry es in zip1)
    {
        es.Extract(TargetDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    }
}
```

Как мне в этой библиотеке изменить кодировку извлекаемых файлов? Получается что извлекаются файлы с кракозяброй в имени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var options = new ReadOptions
{
    Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(866)
};

using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile, options))
```